# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs when connecting keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware

Ubuntu 16.04 hangs when connecting a keyboard or touchpad. The only way to regain access is hard restart.

Comment: So the problem is likely to be related with hardware, not the OS.